# Length of rod, given proper length

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I am starting an introductory modern physics course and am in need of help/guidance with the following problem. I've included the question and my work, and would appreciate people looking over my solution and pointing out any oversights or incorrect reasoning.

As viewed from the lab frame, two rods (each of proper length $L_0$) travel toward each other with equal speed $v$ parallel to their length. What is the length of each rod in the rest frame of the other rod?

It seems to me that the rods will each measure the same length, since they are identical in length and moving at identical speeds.  So, we use the relation

\begin{eqnarray}
L = \frac{L_0}{1 + \frac{v_r^2}{c^2}}
\end{eqnarray}

where $L$ is the contracted length measured by the rods, and $v_r$ is the relative velocity.

The relative velocity (in this case) is given by

\begin{eqnarray}
v_r = \frac{2v}{1 + \frac{v^2}{c^2}}
\end{eqnarray}

where $v$ is the velocity measured from the lab frame.

Plugging $v_r$ into the equation for $L$ (and doing some tedious algebra, which I've spared you all from), we get

\begin{eqnarray}
L = \frac{L_0(c^2+v^2)^2}{(c^2+v^2)^2 + 4v^2c^2}
\end{eqnarray}

where $L, L_0,$ and $v$ are defined as above.  Note that when $v=0$, the above equality reduces to $L=L_0$, which makes sense. Similarly, when $v=c$, the equality becomes $L=\frac{L_0}{2}$, which seems reasonable.

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it.

Comment: 1. Wait for someone whom is more knowledgeable than I, they will come but are probably busy. 2. Both equal *except* direction still means both are equal is correct. 3. When one rests and the other continues both change length. 4. Both rest means both equal. 5. "When v=c" can not occur if they have length (and thus mass), thus is not reasonable; have your "rod" be a pulse of light (in a perfect vacuum) if you want to travel that fast - otherwise there's no circumstances which that could occur (unless you have infinite energy available).

Comment: Check your formula here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/tdil.html - see "Lorentz Transformation".

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Rob in the comments, your formula for the relativistic contraction is incorrect;  it should be
$$
L = L_0 \sqrt{1 - \frac{v_r^2}{c^2}}.
$$

Note also that as the speed of the rods in the lab frame approaches $c$, their relative speed approaches $c$ as well.  The apparent length of an object goes to 0 as its speed approaches $c$.  Thus, each rod should see the other's length approach 0 as $v \to c$;  your answer's limit of $L_0/2$ doesn't actually make sense.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you.  You're absolutely right.  Thanks for pointing out that my formula for $L$ was incorrect.  I'll plug in $v_r$ into that correct formula and give an update when finished with the algebra/simplification.

Comment: Ok, as mentioned above, I plugged in the expression for $v_r$ into the equality for $L$.  Simplifying gave me this equality: $L = \frac{L_0(c-v)(c+v)}{c^2+v^2}$.  This seems to be more reasonable; when $v$ goes to $0$, the limit of $L$ is $L_0$; when $v$ goes to c, the limit of $L$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly apply the velocity addition formula, which links Rod 1 to Rod 2 via the Lab Frame. The problem is you use an analogous formula for length contraction--and that does not work because the velocity addition formula incorporates both length contraction and time dilation. The latter is not a factor in length contraction. That formula was given by @Michael Seifert:

$$ L = L_0/\gamma $$

where

$$ \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$$

is the Lorentz factor, and

$$ \beta = \frac{v}{c} $$

is the velocity in natural units.

Finally, your guess that each rod will measure the same length (of the other rod) is entirely correct--thanks to the symmetry of the situation.